# 2D Textures are shown through objects in front of it(OpenGL)

Tags: opengl, textures, pyglet

I am learning to use pyglet and learning about applying 2D textures to planes in pyglet.  When I apply the 2D texture to the plane it works fine.   When I make multiple objects with the same texture , one in front of the other, i have a problem.

The texture behind the first texture draws through it.  And the texture behind that has the same property.

I would like to disable this so the front texture is shown and obscures the back textures.

In my resize function I called

```
glClearDepth(1.0)
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL)
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)
```

and in my on_draw function i call

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
```

I am using a perspective camera 
with

```
gluLookAt(velx,0,vely,velx,0,vely-10,0,1,0);
```

where velx is the x position for the camera
and vely is the z position for the camera

Am I processing the texture incorrectly causing this?  What should I do to change this?

The images positions are in order on the z axis -10,-20,-40, and -60.

[EDIT]
Here is a screenshot of what I was saying
[image]
The GreenBox is in the front and the Red box is behind it

This is the drawing function that i am using.  I believe that it is clearing the depth buffer.

```
@window.event
```

def on_draw():

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

for x in range(0,4):
    for y in range(0,4):
        glPushMatrix()
        if x % 2== 0 and y % 2==0:
            glBindTexture(texture.target,texture.id)
        else:
            glBindTexture(texture2.target,texture2.id)   
        glTranslatef(x*4.0,0,y*-10.0)
        glBegin(GL_QUADS)

        glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0)
        glVertex3f(-1,-1,-10)
        glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0)
        glVertex3f(-1,1,-10)
        glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0) 
        glVertex3f(1,1,-10)
        glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0)
        glVertex3f(1,-1,-10)

        glEnd()

        glPopMatrix()
```

Comment: You might consider adding a screenshot

Comment: What is your projection matrix? You may have a Z computation issue;  as a quick test you can try to use a clear depth of `-1.0` and `GL_GEQUAL` instead.

Comment: I have updated the original question with a screenshot.  I have tried a clear depth of -1.0 and GL_GEQUAL and it yields similar results.

Comment: @user700508 When do you actually clear the depth buffer? Do you do it once, or everytime that you render a square? Looks liks you are loosing depth information at some point... Maybe more code could help us in finding the error

Comment: Sorry for the lack of code for where it references the clear function.  I have added the draw function to show where I am calling glClear and what I am clearing and what I am drawing.  Maybe I am doing something fundamentally wrong there.

Comment: So it turns out something was wrong, i think it is my graphics card.  I am using an ati 6670 card on windows 8 and on my linux mint laptop it ran fine.